# How to turn the following recursive function into a pure function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, functional-programming

The following function appends an object into a nested array (by searching for it recursively):

```
function appendDeep (arr, obj, newObj) {
  if (arr.indexOf(obj) !== -1) {
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(obj) + 1, 0, newObj)
  } else {
    arr.map(item => {
      if (item.children) spliceDeep(item.children, obj)
    })
  }
}
```

Example:

```
const colors = {
  children: [
    {
      name: 'white',
    },
    {
      name: 'yellow',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'black'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const color = {
  name: 'black'
}

const newColor = {
  name: 'brown'
}

appendDeep(colors.children, color, newColor)
```

Result:

```
children: [
     [
       {
         name: 'white',
       },
       {
         name: 'yellow',
         children: [
           {
             name: 'black'
           },
           {
             name: 'brown'
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   ]
```

As you can see `appendDeep` returns a side-effect; it modifies `arr`. So I decided to return the array instead (so the function would become pure):

```
function findDeep (arr, obj) {
  if (arr.indexOf(obj) !== -1) {
    console.log(arr)
    return arr
  } else {
    arr.map(item => {
      if (item.children) findDeep(item.children, obj)
    })
  }
}
```

And use the new function like this:

```
const newArr = findDeep(colors.children, color)
newArr.splice(newArr.indexOf(color) + 1, 0, newColor)
```

But I get this error:

```
bundle.js:19893 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined
```

What I'm a doing wrong?

(Note: Here's the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/alexcheninfo/pen/ZWopGq).)

(Note 2: `console.log(arr)` does return the nested children. But for some reason they become `undefined` outside of the function.)

Comment: please change `color` and `newColor` to a valid object. please add the wanted result, too.

Comment: @NinaScholz Okay, I made the changes.

Comment: `colors.children` is an array that contains one item, which is another array. That's probably not what you want, and certainly not what your code is expecting.

Comment: @Arjan You're right. I updated the question and the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a find method that will return the array in which the requested item is located (as a direct child).

```
function findDeep(arr, obj) {
    return arr.map((item) => {
        if (item.name === obj.name) {
            return arr;
        } else if (item.children) {
            return findDeep(item.children, obj);
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    }).reduce((prev, cur) => {
        return prev ? prev : cur;
    });
}
```

You could use that to append items to the list, but that will still modify the original array:

```
function appendDeep(arr, color, newColor) {
    let found = findDeep(arr, color);

    if (found) {
        found.splice(found.indexOf(color) + 1, 0, newColor);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

If you don't want to modify the original array, things get more complex. That's because the standard array functions such as `push` and `splice` will modify the original array. There's no quick fix, at least not that I know of, because preferably you would not want to clone any more items than you really have to.

You don't need to clone `black`, but you do need to clone the array that contains it (It can simply reuse the existing object for black.) That means the object for yellow also needs to be cloned (to use the cloned array) and the array in which yellow is located needs to be cloned. But white, which is in the same array, is not modified and does not need to be cloned. I've not figured out how to do that properly.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I spent the whole day on this. `findDeep` kept logging `undefined`. The part that made everything work was `.reduce((prev, cur) => {
        return prev ? prev : cur
    })`. How come it works with that piece and not without it?

By the way isn't `prev ? prev : cur` the same as `prev || cur`?

Comment: `map` converts an array into another array by applying the function to each element of the array. [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) converts an array to a single item by applying the function to each element (`cur`) and also providing the function with the previous or intermediate outcome. You can also supply an initial value. In this case I didn't need an initial value. And yes, `prev || cur` yields the same result as `prev ? prev : cur`. I don't know if either has other benefits.

Comment: `prev ? prev : cur` throw an `Uneccesary use of conditoinal assignment` in ESLint, ha. Thanks for helping, and explaining everything.

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning you recursive `findDeep` method within the `map`. Return that for the recursion to work because your conditional branch is not returning anything from within map. As a result you are getting the result as `undefined`. [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cigupu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: I tried this: `arr.map(item => {
          if (item.children) return findDeep(item.children, obj)
        })` but I'm still getting `undefined`.

Comment: I have added a JSBin with working code sample. Check it now. It should work

Comment: With your code, I get something like this: `[undefined, Array[2], undefined]`. Instead of the matched array.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proposal which uses `thisArgs` of [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
function appendDeep(object, search, insert) {
    function iter(a) {
        if (a.name === search.name) {
            this.children.push(insert);
            return true;
        }
        return Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.some(iter, a);
    }

    object.children.some(iter, object);
}

var colors = { children: [{ name: 'white', }, { name: 'yellow', children: [{ name: 'black' }] }] },
    color = { name: 'black' },
    newColor = { name: 'brown' };

appendDeep(colors, color, newColor);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(colors, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```